# Как написать генератор словаря (dict comprehension), использующий две коллекции

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
{x: y for x in range(4) for y in range(4)}
```

Возвращает:

```
{0: 3, 1: 3, 2: 3, 3: 3}
```

Нужно получить:

```
{0: 0, 1: 1, 2: 2, 3: 3}
```

Знаю, что можно было просто сделать так:

```
{x: x for x in range(4)}
```

Но вот, если я хочу сделать вывод

```
{0: 15, 1: 16, 2: 17, 3: 18}
```

то так не получится:

```
{x: y for x in range(4) for y in range(15, 19) }
```

Comment: а что нужно получить на выходе?

Comment: Потому что на каждой итерации цикла вы перезаписываете значение словаря по ключу.

Comment: Если вы хотите получить `{0: [0, 1, 2, 3], 1: [0, 1, 2, 3], 2: [0, 1, 2, 3], 3: [0, 1, 2, 3]}`, то это так `{x: list(range(4)) for x in range(4)}`.

Comment: @mkkik , спасибо, но я имел ввиду {0: 0, 1: 1, 2: 2, 3: 3}. Знаю, что туповатый пример, но вот как-то так. Знаю что можно было просто указать {x: x for x in range(4)}, Но вот если я хочу сделать вывод :{0: 15, 1: 16, 2: 17, 3: 18} ,  так не получиться {x: y for x in range(4) for y in range(15, 19) }

Comment: `{x: y for x, y in zip(range(4), range(15,19))}`

Comment: Перенес информацию из комментария в вопрос.

Answer (score 3):

Для генерации словаря `{0: 15, 1: 16, 2: 17, 3: 18}` можно использовать следующие варианты:

1. С использованием `zip` (вариант, предложенный @mkkik):

   ```
   {x: y for x, y in zip(range(4), range(15,19))}
   ```
2. С использованием `zip`, передав результат в конструктор словаря напрямую (предложено @jfs):

   ```
   dict(zip(keys, values))
   ```
3. Арифметически (хотя, скорее всего это не то, что требуется):

   ```
   {x: x + 15 for x in range(4)}
   ```

Comment: `zip` можно в конструктор напрямую передать: `dict(zip(keys, values))`

Answer (score 0):

```
d = {a: 15 + a for a in range(5)}
print(d)
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на [ru.so]! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы.